# How to grep to find files that has wildcard string

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to find the list of files/filenames in a directory that has string “bla bla no user exists bla bla”. The string inside the file that I should supply is like “*no user exists*” that should return all the file names that has this wildcard string.
Can some pls help.

Comment: `grep -l "no user exists" *`

Answer (score 0):

You use the `grep` program.

```
grep "no user exists" FILE1 FILE2 FILE3 ...
```

That's not a "wildcard string". That's just a string to search for, and grep will show you ever line that matches in every file.

If all you want is a list of files, use the `-l` option.

```
grep -l "no user exists" FILE1 FILE2 FILE3 ...
```